# "Begrudging Conditional"

Tags: conditionals

How might you express a rude, begrudging permission in Japanese? I realize this is something you'd never encounter in practice or in public, but I'm writing a fictional story about some rather rude people so it's useful to know.

Sentences I have in mind here:

"If you must stay, stay in this room."

"If you must drink, drink my water."

"If you must come with us, help us carry."

Comment: How about 「どうしてもというのなら」「どうしてもいるというのなら/いたいというのなら」「どうしても来たいのなら/来たいというのなら・・・」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the below is just your examples.

> "If you must stay, stay in this room."
>
> 居るんなら、ここに居ろ
>
> "If you must drink, drink my water."
>
> 水を飲むなら、僕の水を飲め
>
> "If you must come with us, help us carry."
>
> 来るんなら、一緒に運べ

There are plenty of situations where you need to be forceful. I am not saying that you would use these examples, but there are times when you need to give orders and it can come across quite harsh.

Comment: I suggest 俺の水を飲め. It is more rude than 僕の水を飲め.

Comment: @YuuichiTam, did not want to sound like a complete jerk. LOL　I am going to leave it as is, your comment is enough I feel.

Comment: Well, rather than truly *rude*, I'm really going for more "imperious," the sort of thing that might get used in a military command - or an incantation, for that matter. These seem about right, though.

Comment: @linkhyrule5,  I think you will find that even in military  「俺」 would be used.   I did not use it b/c, I have heard foreigners here in Japan use 「俺」 and it sound strange, unless they were really , really good at speaking.

Comment: Well, in the particular context of an incantation, she's probably going to be using 「我が」 instead. I was mostly looking for the imperious conditional.

Comment: @linkhyrule5, "imperious conditional", don't quite know what you are saying here , sorry.

Comment: Mm, it's a tonal thing that I don't know if Japanese strictly has, which is why I accepted this one. Like, in English, if you start with "If you truly must...", there's a very strong connotation of exasperation/disapproval attached to it. A sort of "I disapprove of this entire course of action, so at least do this one thing."

Comment: 「どうしてもというのなら・・」とかですかね・・

Comment: @linkhyrule5, definitely has those connotations. It is as if you are fed up and you just don't won't to argue any more, sort of like "well suit your self, I have had enough" I just did not understand that last bit you said.